# Convergence in probability to a random variable X and a random variable Y implies X = Y a.s.

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, random-variables

I need a bit of help with this proof. I think it is probably trivial but I can't get my head around it right now.

Given a sequence of r.v. $X_n$ which converges in probability to a random variable X and another random variable $\bar{X}$ it follows that $X = \bar{X}$ a.s.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.

Comment: It might be easier to think about in the case that $P(X=0)=1$.

Comment: @kimchilover Hmm I don't really see how this changes the whole thing? I thought of using some kind of Borel Cantelli argument but I'm not sure how to get a basis here for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $\delta>0$ you have $P(|X_n-X|<\delta/2)\to1$ and also $P(|X_n-\overline X|<\delta/2)\to 1$.  So $P(\max(|X_n-X|,|X_n-\overline X|)<\delta/2)\to1$. But the event that $[\max(|X_n-X|,|X_n-\overline X|)<\delta/2]$ is a subset of the event that $[|X-\overline X|<\delta]$.  That is, $1\le P(|X-\overline X|<\delta)$, for each positive $\delta$.  So it must be the case that $P(X=\overline X)=1$.

Comment: Love the proof and love kimchi too.